# Saving Django ModelForm with a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

This is probably a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out from the Django Docs. I'm trying to save a two ModelForms at once with one being a ForeignKey of another. I'm not sure how to write the logic in the views to ensure these go together properly.

**models.py**

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateStore1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        exclude = ('address',)

class CreateStore2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = CreateStore1Form(request.POST)
        form2 = CreateStore2Form(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            store = form1.save(address)
            new_address = form2.save(commit=False)
            new_address.store = store
            mew_address.save()
    else:
        form1 = CreateStore1Form()
        form2 = CreateStore2Form()
    return render(request, 'create.html', locals())
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help [Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django)

Comment: Did some of the answers help you?

Comment: For the sake of all active StackOverflow users, if you get a solution that works, please mark the answer as accepted, so that people don't spend time answering if answer is not needed anymore.

Comment: I was still running into an issue. I'll update this thread with a solution or mark a working answer. Sorry for leaving this thread open for so long.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django provides [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for this use case:

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key.

forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        exclude = ('address',)
```

views.py

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

@login_required
def create(request):    
    AddressInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Address, Store, form=AddressForm)

     if request.method == 'POST':
         storeForm = StoreForm(request.POST)

         if storeForm.is_valid():
             new_store = storeForm.save()
             addressInlineFormSet = AddressInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_store)

             if addressInlineFormSet.is_valid():
                addressInlineFormSet.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_happy_customer_url'))

             else:
                classificationformset = ClassificationInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_store)
     else:
          addressInlineFormSet = AddressInlineFormSet()
          storeForm = StoreForm()
     return render(request, 'create.html', locals())
```

Please see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267810/django-formset-without-instance) for more details.