# Django form validation and action on two models

Tags: django, django-forms

I haven't got much experience with building custom forms (only default model forms) and I'm looking for some help here. I'm trying to build a form that will get "feed_url" from user and if it already exist, just add reference into UserFeed model. In case it doesn't exist, it should add it to the Feed model and also reference it in UserFeed model as well.

models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', always_update='True', unique_with='user')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class Feed(models.Model):
    feed_url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.feed_url


class UserFeed(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', always_update='True', unique_with='user')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)
```

forms

```
class UserFeedForm(forms.Form):
    feed_url = forms.URLField()
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category)
    user = forms.HiddenInput()
```

views

```
def addfeed(request):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    feeds = Feed.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserFeedForm(request.POST)
        form.fields['category'].queryset = categories
        if form.is_valid():
            feed = form.save(commit=False)
            if form.fields['feed_url'] in feeds:
                ##### add to Feed object and add reference to UserFeed object
                feed.user = request.user
                feed.save()
            else:
                ##### get id from Feed object and add reference to UserFeed object
                feed.user = request.user
                feed.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/reader/manage")
    else:
        form = UserFeedForm()
        form.fields['category'].queryset = categories
    context = {'form': form,}
    return expand_context_and_render(request, context, 'reader/form.html')
```

Could anybody please point me in the right direction?
thanks

**UPDATE** 
Now I have updated my view and form as follows:

forms

```
class UserFeedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    feed = forms.URLField()
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category)
    user = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = UserFeed
        fields = ['feed', 'title', 'category']
```

views

```
def addfeed(request):
    categories = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    feeds = Feed.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserFeedForm(request.POST)
        form.fields['category'].queryset = categories
        if form.is_valid():
            feed = form.cleaned_data.get('feed')
            if feed in feeds:
                ##### get id from Feed and add reference to UserFeed
                existing_feed = Feed.objects.get(feed_url=feed)
                form.feed = existing_feed.id
                form.user = request.user
                form.save(commit=True)
            else:
                ##### add to Feed object and then add reference to UserFeed object
                Feed.object.create(feed_url=feed)
                existing_feed = Feed.objects.get(feed_url=feed)
                form.feed = existing_feed.id
                form.user = request.user
                form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/reader/manage")
    else:
        form = UserFeedForm()
        form.fields['category'].queryset = categories
    context = {'page_title': page_title,
               'form': form,
               }
    return expand_context_and_render(request, context, 'reader/form.html')
```

I think I'm getting closer but it still won't work, giving me this error:
"Cannot assign "u'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml'": "UserFeed.feed" must be a "Feed" instance."

Any idea how can I fix this?
thanks

Comment: What precisely are you having trouble with? What don't you understand?

Comment: Well basically in those two sections where I added two comments with ##### I'm not sure how to populate it it functionality

Comment: For using `form.save()` you should be using `modelForm`.

Comment: @Rohan - yes this is good point, but overall I'm still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working like this:

forms

```
class UserFeedForm(forms.Form):
    feed = forms.URLField()
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(Category)
    user = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = UserFeed
        fields = ['feed', 'title', 'category']
```

views

```
def addfeed(request):
    user = request.user
    categories = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserFeedForm(request.POST)
        form.fields['category'].queryset = categories
        if form.is_valid():
            feed = form.cleaned_data['feed']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            feed_obj, created = Feed.objects.get_or_create(feed_url=feed)
            obj = UserFeed(feed=feed_obj, title=title, category=category, user=user)
            obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/reader/manage")
    else:
        form = UserFeedForm()
        form.fields['category'].queryset = categories
    context = {'page_title': page_title,
               'form': form,
               }
    return expand_context_and_render(request, context, 'reader/form.html')
```

Both tips from the answers below pointed me in the right direction. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639391/saving-django-modelform-with-a-foreignkey), and also [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) in the docs.

Additionally in your UserFieldForm, `feed` is defined as a `URLField`. So in your view, in this line:

```
feed = form.get_cleaned_data.get('feed')
```

your feed variable is simply a string, and not actually a Feed object. This is where your error might be occurring? That's where `inline formsets` could help you. Also, this line also makes your your `if feed in feeds:` statement moot, because `feed` is just a string, whereas `feeds` is a Queryset of all your Feed instances. I think this will cause your view to always end up in the `else` block?

I'm new to Django myself but I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you are looking for is:

1. Check if the feed exists.
2. If it exists, fetch it.
3. If it doesn't create a new feed.
4. Associate the feed with a `UserFeed` object.

The [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method does parts 1-3, so you need the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    feed = form.cleaned_data.get('feed')
    feed_obj, created = Feed.objects.get_or_create(feed_url=feed)
    obj.feed = feed_obj
    obj.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/reader/manage")
```

Comment: It seems like a good solution but despite having "obj.feed = feed_obj" it still sees feed as a string for some reason. I'm getting this error still: "Cannot assign "u'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml'": "UserFeed.feed" must be a "Feed" instance." ANy idea ?

Comment: You might have reassigned `feed_obj` somewhere else.

Comment: No, I double checked and this is not the case. Would you know any other ways to solve it maybe ?