# Altering two Django ModelForms in one form, where one has a ForeignKey for the other

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My question is pretty much identical to this one: [Saving Django ModelForm with a ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639391/saving-django-modelform-with-a-foreignkey), however when I tried what the accepted answer suggested, I got the following error:

"FieldError at /myapp/adduser"

"Unknown field(s) (address1, address4, postcode, address3, address2) specified for Users"

My files are as follows:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Addresses(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Users(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Addresses)

class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Addresses
        fields = ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode']

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'dob']
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import AddressForm, Addresses, UserForm, Users

def adduser(request):
    AddressInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Addresses, Users, form=AddressForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userForm = UserForm(request.POST)

        if userForm.is_valid():
            new_user = userForm.save()
            addressInlineFormSet = AddressInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_user)

            if addressInlineFormSet.is_valid():
                addressInlineFormSet.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/thanks/'))

            else:
                classificationformset = ClassificationInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_user)

    else:
        addressInlineFormSet = AddressInlineFormSet()
        userForm = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'myapp/adduser.html', locals())
```

I'm also unclear on whether there are any problems with 'adduser.html'. I've got the following:

**adduser.html**

```
<h1>Create a new user</h1>

<form action="adduser" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ userForm }}
    {{ addressInlineFormSet }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any guidance on how to fix the problem would be very much appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's the full traceback, as requested:

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/myname/mysite/myapp/views.py" in adduser
  56.     AddressInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Addresses, Users, form=AddressForm)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in inlineformset_factory
  1049.     FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in modelformset_factory
  847.                              error_messages=error_messages, field_classes=field_classes)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in modelform_factory
  545.     return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __new__
  257.                 raise FieldError(message)

Exception Type: FieldError at /myapp/adduser
Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (address3, address2, address4, postcode, address1) specified for Users
```

Comment: Your error said: `Unknown field(s) (address1, address4, postcode, address3, address2) specified for Users`, usually it's because you had the wrong model(`User`) combined with fields(`address1`, etc) in form definition, but your code looks correct. Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes, several times - and the error remains...

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: I've edited the original question to include the full traceback.