# How to save two forms in one view with a foreignkey relationship?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models with foreignkey relation.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

     profile_id = models.CharField(
          ('Profile id'), max_length=30, default='', blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        ('first name'), max_length=30, default='', blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(
    ('last name'), default='', max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Profile Image model has a foreignkey relation to UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfileImage(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic/images',blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.userprofile.profile_id
```

I want to save both forms in one view and for edit also it should pass both form instances.How will I save both forms in one view?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Create both in one form?

Comment: I think you should read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Please, look at this answer and do like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639772/5751530

Comment: Are inline formsets the answer or did you never find the answer? I have the EXACT same question.