# How to save a model in ModelForm with two ForeignKey fields in Django

Tags: python, html, django

There is a model Listaflor linked to Estados with another model named Flora2Estado, i made a form with ModelMultipleChoiceField. It saves successfully into Listaflor but nothing into the Flora2Estado, what can i do about this?

forms.py

```
class FloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    familia = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Familia.objects.all().order_by('familia_nome').filter(aprovado=1))
    Especie = forms.CharField(label="Nome da espécie*")
    estados = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=EstadosM.objects.all().order_by('nome_abbr'))
    class Meta:
        model = Listaflor
        ordering = ["estados",]
        fields = ['Especie','estados']
```

views.py

```
def CreateFlo(request):
    form = FloForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Listaflor = form.save(commit=False)
            Flora2Estado = form.save(commit=False)
            Listaflor.save()
            Flora2Estado.save()
  
    return render(request,'accounts/enviar_flora.html')
```

models.py

```
class Flora2Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadosM, models.CASCADE)
    especie = models.ForeignKey(Listaflor, models.CASCADE)
    flora2estado = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie'),)
```

Any tips on helping me making a better post is welcome, have a good day!

View.py updated: returning Validation error!

```
def CreateFlo(request):    
    EstadosInlineFormSet  = inlineformset_factory(Listaflor, Flora2Estado, form=Flo2Form)
    Form = FloForm(request.POST)
    storeForm = FloForm(request.POST)
    if Form.is_valid():
        new_store = storeForm.save()
        florInlineFormSet = EstadosInlineFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=new_store)

        if florInlineFormSet.is_valid():
            florInlineFormSet.save()
    context = {'form': Form}
    return render(request,'accounts/enviar_flora.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Flora2Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadosM, models.CASCADE)
    especie = models.ForeignKey(Listaflor, models.CASCADE)
    flora2estado = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flora2estado'
        unique_together = (('estado', 'especie'),)
class Listaflor(models.Model):
    especie_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    familia = models.ForeignKey(Familia, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='familia_id', blank=True, null=True)
    Especie = models.CharField(db_column='especie', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I tried this:

```
def CreateFlo(request):
    form = FloForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            listafor = form.save()
            estados = form.cleaned_data.get('estados')
            for estado in estados:
                Flora2Estado.objects.create(especie=listafor, estado= estado)
    texto="..."
    context = {'floForm': form,'texto': texto}
    return render(request, 'accounts/enviar_flora.html', context)
```

got the error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '18-3256' for
> key 'PRIMARY'")

[image: error!]

Comment: It is not clear that what your actual requirement is

Comment: to save in two models at the same time with foreign key

Comment: What about EstadosM? Is it already saved before? Is Flora2Estado already save with EstadosM?

Comment: the models are fully working on the front end and django admin, only thing to do now is to make the form.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have clearly mentioned `Listaflor` here:

```
class Meta:
    model = Listaflor
```

Eventhough if you've changed it to

```
class Meta:
    model = Flora2Estado
```

You can't save the `ForeignKey` fields in `Flora2Estado` like that.

Let's have a look at this on [Saving Django `ModelForm` with a `ForeignKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639772/11282077)

Comment: i'm getting this: ValidationError at /enviar_flora/
['the data from ManagementForm...

Comment: This would be another question. Please provide ManagementForm, view and models code along with the error text or screenshot.

Comment: I made a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013168/django-managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with-foreign-manyto

Comment: i would love to get it working, thank you for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify two unique prefixes to differentiate between the forms:

```
form1 = FloForm(prefix='form-1')
form2 = FloForm(prefix='form-2')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = FloForm(request.POST,prefix='form-1')
    form2 = FloForm(request.POST,prefix='form-2')
    if form.is_valid():
        Listaflor = form1.save(commit=False)
        Flora2Estado = form2.save(commit=False)
        Listaflor.save()
        Flora2Estado.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract out the `estados` from form's `cleaned_data`, like this:

```
def CreateFlo(request):
    form = FloForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            listafor = form.save()
            estados = form.cleaned_data.get('estados')
            for estado in estados:
                Flora2Estado.objects.create(especie=listafor, estado= estado)
            # or you can use bulk_create: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create
  
    return render(request,'accounts/enviar_flora.html')
```

### Update

It is really hard to tell for which model you are getting the error, but my assumption is Listaflor model. It is a possibility that you have a primary key field in which default value is “18-XXXX”. When you are creating Listaflor instance using the FloForm, you are not providing any primary key value, so it is taking the default value as primary key, hence throwing Integrity error. To solve this you can either use a [dynamic function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654998/2696165) to generate the value of primary key or use [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)/[AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#autofield) to generate primary key automatically.

Comment: got: IntegrityError at /enviar_flora/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '18-3223' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Comment: Can you please add the full error stack trace on the question? Also for which model do you get the error?

Comment: Your awnser got me the closest to the solution! but i still can't get it to work, i posted the error in the question!!

Comment: thank you,  i'm getting the error for flora2estados, i looked for the key in the db. the problem is, it already uses autofield, i will try to use the dynamic function.

Comment: did you run migrations and migrate commands?

Comment: The error says it is due to primary key. Can you please try to create a Flora2Estado instance in django shell to see if this problem occurs or not?

Comment: ,succesfully added

>>>obj0 = Listaflor.objects.create(especie_id=9999, Especie="teste")

>>> obj = EstadosM.objects.create(estado_nome="teste, nome_abbr="tt")  

>>> obj2 = Flora2Estado.objects.create(estado=obj, especie=obj0)

Comment: yes!,the whole models are working, i can add items on the django admin without a hitch

Comment: Okay, that means the problem is somewhere in the code. I will try to debug or reproduce it in my local machine and let you know later today or tomorrow

Comment: thank you very much!! here's the bounty :)

Comment: Hi, I could not reproduce the issue, but I found out that the `Flora2Estado`'s table is not managed by django ORM, meaning all the changes there has to be made manually(because of `managed=False` in model meta). So, auto field might not work if it was not migrated into DB table, meaning `flora2estado` could be something other than a autofield.

Comment: After I migrated properly in DB, all the code seems to be working just fine and generating `Flora2Estdao` instances from form.save().

Comment: Hello! i changed flora2estado managed to true without success...

Comment: actually, the error steems from listaflor, it creates things in the db but throws the error anyway

Comment: To fix the migration, what I did was drop flora2estado table from DB, comment out Flora2Estado code, then ran makemigration and ‘./manage.py migrate —fake’, then undo the commented out part, ran migrations and migrate command. I used the same code as yours, I just used some simpler models for Famila and EstadioM.

Comment: If listaflor is throwing error then my assumption was correct in the first place, please see if the migration is managed by Django or not, if not please use the procedure mentioned above

Comment: now lista flora and flora2estado managed=True!! still got the error

Comment: strange because it create in the db the key that shows "duplicate" like it's trying to create two listaflors

Comment: isn't the problem in the listaflor = form.save()? should't it just send the especie_id to the newly created instance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071889/django-duplicate-key-when-trying-to-send-a-form-with-foreign-key

Comment: For now, you can add a hack solution which is to add a try catch. But still, this is not a real solution. Unfortunately the code given here is working in my DB. Can you maybe try with a new DB to see if this error occurs or not. For fresh setup, you should delete the migration files from apps directory and then run makemigrations and migrate command.